# X11VNC & TightVNC Viewer some keys don't work

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I have configured an `x11vnc` server on my `Ubuntu 16.04` machine to which I mostly connect from `TightVNC Viewer` on Win 10 clients.

This works exceptionally well except that some keys are not correctly interpreted:

- <kbd>{</kbd> does nothing (maybe it's <kbd>AltGr</kbd> in generall...)
- The `NumPad` doesn't seem to work at all and therefore keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumPadX</kbd> to position windows etc.

This is just a short excerpt and there are maybe other keys I can't think of right now which don't work as expected.

Both, the host & clients have a German keyboard layout installed.

I can't seem to find anything useful in the `TightVNC Viewers` options.
Is there anything I can tweak with `x11vnc` start parameters?