# What in dpkg-reconfigure makes x11vnc keyboard layout work?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, vnc

My Setup:
Server: Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop (German) with x11vnc
Client: Windows 7 (German) with TightVNC

Problem:
After each boot the VNC session has a wrong keyboard layout (e.g. `|` produces `'`).

My solution:
Open a terminal within the VNC session and call `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`, accepting all defaults

Output in the console:

```
Your console font configuration will be updated the next time your system
boots. If you want to update it now, run 'setupcon' from a virtual console.
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Trigger für initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) werden verarbeitet ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-64-generic
```

(Sorry for the german "Trigger für ...")

Now I realized that not all steps are necessary: The layout is already corrected before the line `update-initramfs: deferring ...` appears.

In fact, I can even press Ctrl-C directly after returning from the 'graphical' screens and it still fixes the problem.

So I wonder:

- **What is happening that actually sets the correct VNC mode?**
- **Is there another way to achieve this effect?**
- Whou could walk me through until I found the solution?

I'm glad to provide more information as requested.

Cross-reference to similar questions:
[x11vnc under Ubuntu 16.10 - wrong keyboard mapping when accessing from Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844723/x11vnc-under-ubuntu-16-10-wrong-keyboard-mapping-when-accessing-from-windows-7#comment1373467_844723)
[X11VNC & TightVNC Viewer some keys don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810839/x11vnc-tightvnc-viewer-some-keys-dont-work)

*Different problem without a solution:

[VNC: pressing Shift + Tab = Tab only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839842/vnc-pressing-shift-tab-tab-only#comment1384101_839842)*

Can anybody give a hint as to what happens under the hood of `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`?

Comment: Is there possibly a keyboard layout setting in TightVNC?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson No.
I'd like to know what happens during `dpkg-reconfigure` that might change the VNC layout.